# Как добавить все возможные города в EditText?

Tags: java, android

Как добавить все возможные города в EditText, то есть сделать searchbar для всех городов?

Comment: для начала вам надо просто найти список всех городов. И дальше - добавить список строк в searchbar. Так что разбейте вашу задачу на 2 части, и решайте их отдельно.

Comment: вот тут хорошо все описано  https://androidhub.intel.com/en/posts/nglauber/Android_Search.html. только вот вам нужно свои города взять

Comment: @Senior Automator спасибо!

Comment: @metalurgus  хорошо)

Answer (score 4):

вот [тут](https://androidhub.intel.com/en/posts/nglauber/Android_Search.html) хорошо все описано

только вот вам нужно свои города взять, вместо списка https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6802536/cidades.json

Создайте свой объект со списками всех городов и укажите доступ к нему

Answer (score 1):

Есть очень хороший скрипт с множеством примеров и большими возможностями.

https://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/

Данные берутся из Google Maps.

Comment: Вроде на джаве автор хочет примеры

Comment: Точно, не глянул на теги.